# ASP.NET MVC 3 model binding not working for me?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

This is the line that is not working:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder())
```

To be more precise. Binders is highlated.

[I found this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx) by Phil Haack.

I did all it said, added refrences to `using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders;`
Added class `public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder`to a new folder and told to Global.ascx about the folder. But the red line keeps showing underneath the **Binders**. Can you help me?

Comment: I think you should contact phil haack via its blog rather than asking here. Kindly

Comment: What does the "red line" say?

Comment: But he well not even notice it, as it was written 1 and a half year ago. Thank you for sugestion

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Binders' does not exist in the namespace 'RoomReservation.Wep.ModelBinders' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Visual_Studio_2010_Workspace\RoomReservation\RoomReservation\RoomReservation.Wep\Global.asax.cs 40 26 RoomReservation.Wep

Comment: @TunAntun Personally, I get questions to articles I've written 10 years ago and if the asker is nice and polite, I usually always answer questions.

Comment: Ok, I will try, only thought this would be faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error it looks like it is treating the `ModelBinders` as namespace (which is present in your project) instead of the framework class.

Try using the below line which will resolve the ambiguity.

```
 System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder())
```

Comment: You error `'Binders' does not exist in the namespace 'RoomReservation.Wep.ModelBinders'` clearly tells it is treating `ModelBinders` as part of namespace instead of referring it as a type.

Comment: Great answer. I went with the workaround first (changing the code), but then I realised thanks to the first part of your answer, because it's generated code, that I should just change that namespace in my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler interprets the reference to ModelBinders as a reference to RoomReservation.Wep.ModelBinders. Try using

```
System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder())
```

Comment: `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding` namespace is not having a class called Binders. ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Yes, when I do the above statement change I get Add underscored. So I guess, you are wright, there is no Binders in ModelBinding